# Elastic search match_all filter only return all document when size is specified

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Inside db there 250 tags, when use bellow query it's just returns 5 of them

```
   const { body } = await elasticWrapper.client.search({
        index: ElasticIndex.Tags,
        filter_path: 'hits.hits._source*',
        body: {
          query: {
            match_all: {},
          },
        },
      });
```

but when I specified the size only then it's return all of them

```
   const { body } = await elasticWrapper.client.search({
        index: ElasticIndex.Tags,
        filter_path: 'hits.hits._source*',
        body: {
          from: 0,
          size: 250,
          query: {
            match_all: {},
          },
        },
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior to avoid heavy memory/CPU usage and performance degradation. [Match all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html#query-dsl-match-all-query) query does not mean returning all documents, but it means matching all documents, giving them all same weight (a `_score` of 1.0).

By default, searches return the top 10 matching hits. To page through a larger set of results, you can use [from and size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/paginate-search-results.html) parameters, like what you do in this case.

Comment: thank you, your information is very informative, if you please share me doc link from where I will able to read more about you just wrote.

Comment: @Lord, I did already add links to my post (see "Match all", "from and size").  If this helps you, please consider accepting it as an answer.

Comment: thank you, can you help with this quesion too, thanks in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462805/elasticsearch-node-js-client-delete-a-nested-element-from-a-object