# Elasticsearch Node.js client: delete a nested element from a object

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a object like bellow

```
 "_source": {
                "name": "capsicum",
                "id": "60f759b934e43100195c6142",
                "userId": "60f7209ecdb2c0001935fa8f",
                "version": 1,
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "fruit",
                        "id": "60f75990be3b530019062790",
                        "group": "location"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "green",
                        "id": "60f75990be3b530019062766",
                        "group": "food"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "red",
                        "id": "60f75990be3b530019062722",
                        "group": "food"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "vegetable",
                        "id": "60f75990be3b53001906272d",
                        "group": "food"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

how can I delete one element from tags, add an element in tags, in separate api calls.
I tried bellow code for deleting but not working

```
elasticClient.updateByQuery(
        {
          index: ElasticIndexs.Products,
          body: {
            script: {
              source: `ctx._source.tags.removeIf(a -> a.id == params.id)`,
              params: {
                id: product.tag.id,
              },
            },
            query: {
              match: {
                id: product.id,
              },
            },
          },
        },
        function (error, response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      );
```

Comment: What errors are you getting from the logs?  I believe you are  getting "product.id" and "product.tag.id" from somewhere to this function, can you confirm that those parameters are not undefined when accessed here?

Comment: @HemedAli, thank you for your prompt response, but the problem was some where else, if you have interest to see the ans, you will find it in ans section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for adding:

```
  await elasticWrapper.client.update({
        index: ElasticIndexs.Products,
        id: data.id,
        body: {
          script: {
            inline: 'ctx._source.tags.add(params.tag)',
            // lang: 'painless',
            params: {
              tag: data.tag,
            },
          },
        },
      });
```

for deleting:

```
 await elasticWrapper.client.update({
        index: ElasticIndexs.Products,
        id: data.id,
        body: {
          script: {
            inline: `for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.tags.size();
            i++){if(ctx._source.tags[i].id == params.id){ctx._source.tags.remove(i);}}`,
            params: {
              id: data.tag.id,
            },
          },
        },
      });
```